# Native JavaScript style syntax

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on some native JavaScript (not my forte.. at all) and am not seeing the result of my function. I'm sure I've got a syntax error in here somewhere. Can you help me identify it? FYI- The function will dynamically center an object on the page.

```
this.style[left]= ((windowWidth - this.style[width])/2);
this.style[top]= ((windowHeight - this.style[height])/2);
```

Comment: Are those variables in square brackets? They should be strings if using substring notation

Comment: @Russ Cam - errruhhhgg... Not sure what you mean. Other than yes, there are brackets, although left and top are properties..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have, at least, three problems.

First: The CSS `height`, `width`, `left` and `top` properties take **lengths**. You are passing them **Numbers**.

**You must include a unit.**

Likewise, you need to account for the unit on the values for the width and height.

Second: You also need to balance your parentheses.

Third: When using square bracket notation, you need to pass in *strings*. At the moment, I assume that `left` and `top` are `undefined`.

```
this.style.left = (windowWidth  - parseInt(this.style.width,10)) / 2  + 'px';
this.style.top  = (windowHeight - parseInt(this.style.height,10)) / 2 + 'px';
```

Finally, this will only work if the element has its width and height defined using inline style (or if those properties have been set via JavaScript). Otherwise the values you are trying to read will be `undefined`. In this case you will need to deal with the [computed style](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html).

Also remember that `top` and `left` will have no effect unless the element is [positioned](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioned-element).

Comment: ah, makes sense. I'm not really familiar with how to implement that. Can you give me an example to work from? Thanks!

Comment: That won't work. You are dividing the element width by two and then subtracting that from the window width, so it will place the element halfway outside the window. Also the parentheses doesn't match, so you will get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You omitted a `(`

this.style[left]= ((windowWidth - this.style[width])/2);

this.style[top]= **(**(windowHeight - this.stylep[height])/2);

Answer (score 0):

You also missing an opening `(` on this second line. Other than that, assuming that all the variables you are using there are defined your code seems fine.

```
this.style[left] = ((windowWidth - this.style[width]) / 2);
this.style[top] = ((windowHeight - this.style[height]) / 2);
```

Also this could be written like this:

```
this.style.left = ((windowWidth - this.style.width) / 2);
this.style.top = ((windowHeight - this.style.height) / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting the styles, you should have a unit, e.g. `100px` instead of just `100`.

When reading the style, it will have a unit, so you would need to parse it using the `parseInt` function to get the number in front of the unit.

When accessing properties using brackets, you should use strings, not identifiers:

```
this.style["left"] = ((windowWidth - parseInt(this.style["width"],10)) / 2) + "px";
this.style["top"] = ((windowHeight - parseInt(this.style["height"],10)) / 2) + "px";
```

You can also use the `.` operator to access properties:

```
this.style.left = ((windowWidth - parseInt(this.style.width,10)) / 2) + "px";
this.style.top = ((windowHeight - parseInt(this.style.height,10)) / 2) + "px";
```